# Projectile Motion in GNUPlot and its colour

Tags: animation, gnuplot, projectile

Hello I tried to make a projectile motion using GNUPlot.

This is the way I made the script, first I define a function of y (initial velocity in y is zero, initial velocity in x is 1, initial vertical position is at yinit =34, initial horizontal position is at zero (origin))

(sorry for the ineffective way of making it, I am quite new here)

```
set term post eps color enhanced font "Times, 24"
set size 1.2, 0.8
set bmargin 3.5

set xlabel "{/Italic x} (m)" font "Times, 30"
set xtics 0 0.5 font "Times, 28"
set mxtics 4
set xrange[0:2.5]

set ylabel "{/Italic y} (m)" font "Times, 30"
set ytics 5 font "Times, 28"
set mytics 2
set yrange [0:40]

set grid xtics ytics mxtics mytics

yinit = 34
vxinit = 1
gr = -9.8
y(t) = yinit + 0.5*gr*t*t 
x(t) = vxinit*t

t = 0.0
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""


t = 0.1
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.2
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.3
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.4
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.5
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.6
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.7
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.8
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 0.9
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""

t = 1.0
timestamp = sprintf("{/Italics t} = %1.2f Sekon", t);
filename = sprintf("projectile-%1.1f.eps", t);
set output filename
unset label
set label timestamp at -0.25, -0.28 font ", 28"
plot y(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
plot x(t) w p pt 5 ps 2.5 t ""
```

(still cannot post image here, still have a low reputation)

And about the colour, i want to make blue

Comment: And what's your actual question?

Comment: oh sorry. I cannot plot the animation as it is only showing the graphic of y over x, but not each position over the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need a parametric plot: plot the (x,y)-position at different steps of an independent variable:

```
yinit = 34
vxinit = 1
gr = -9.8
y(t) = yinit + 0.5*gr*t*t 
x(t) = vxinit*t

set parametric
set trange [0:1]
set samples 11
plot x(t), y(t)  with linespoints pt 7 lc rgb 'blue'
```

[image]